# How to reference a a secondary view upon launch of initial view Swift 2, Xcode 7

Tags: swift, swift2

What I want to do is have two views, and the initial view references something, say a UISwitch, in the second view upon the launch of the initial view.

For example:
Two views, each with different associated view controllers.
The first view has, say, a label.
The second one has a UISwitch.
When the app runs on an iPhone, if the switch is on, the label says "Switch is on", same if off.
**But I want the label to change based on the switch on the second view, before the initial view loads. I keep getting an error that says "error: found nil while unwrapping an optional" I don't want to have to go to the second view, I just want the initial view to reference the switch on the second view, in the initial view's viewDidLoad**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. When the App starts, the second view doesn't exist yet, so there is no switch. The second view gets instantiated on-demand by iOS and you don't get to control that unless you want to override the entire NIB loading (StoryBoard) mechanism and write the entire App in pure textual code.

What exists as the App is just starting is a *description* of the switch, sitting in a .nib file (a text file that contains your StoryBoard in XML format). In that description file, the switch does have a specified starting state -- which you set in StoryBoard. Since you know what you set it to when building the App, just use that.

You're asking this because you don't yet understand MVC. What you really want is a *model* class that *represents* the underlying value that the switch is controlling. That can be loaded immediately in your first view controller. Then when the second VC loads, the switch sets itself based on the same model, not the other way around.

MVC has a steep learning curve so right now work with the above constraints as best you can.

You could get by for now if you can accept that you only need to update the first view *when the second one's switch changes*:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBAction switchFlipped(sender: UISwitch) {
       let firstVC = self.presentingViewController as! FirstViewController
       if sender.on {
           firstVC.switchTextLabel.text = "The Switch is On"
       } 
       else {
           firstVC.switchTextLabel.text = "The Switch is Off"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into MVC.

Comment: How do I reference the description in code? I tried if (presentingViewController as! SecondViewController).switch.on.description == "On" and that if statement again without the .on nothing works.

Comment: You're straying off into the wilderness. Present **all** your code in your question. I don't think you're describing things right. It sounds from that snippet that the "second" VC comes up *first* and presents the "initial" VC. Which makes no sense either.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a for instance code, you're right it would be InitialViewController, not SecondViewController. It would be too complicated to paste the code for my app into here (My MacBook isn't on Wi-Fi; I'm typing this from my iPhone).

Comment: You cannot do what you're asking. Re-think the whole problem. It makes sense to want the first view to reflect changes that the user actually made: loading the second view, flipping the switch and then returning from it back to the first. But otherwise, set the switch to be off in StoryBoard and know that it starts out off in the first view, and set the label accordingly. Anything else and you're just going in circles for no reason. Answer updated.